# How do I play Minecraft Hunger Games on Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft Pocket edition has many versions, for example, Survival and Creative. I haven't figured out how to play Hunger Games, though.

I want to play on this game please.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a question and answer site about video games -- you can't actually play anything here.

Comment: I understand that you want to play a game, but I don't understand what you're actually asking. If you want to know how to play games *on this site*, that would be impossible. This site is for asking questions about games and answering them. If you're having trouble launching a game, then we need to know which game it is, on which platform, what you have tried, and where you got stuck. We can't *guess* what your problem is, you need to give us as much information as you can.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you can play Minecraft Hunger Games on Pocket Edition.

Usually, Minecraft Hunger Games is played as a server minigame. This means that it makes use of server commands and it is reset. Because it is found on servers, you can't play on Pocket Edition. Sorry.

On PC, Minecraft Hunger Games is on servers, and the way servers work, no problem! You can also play on Xbox. However, on PE, servers are just worlds on the same WiFi network. No server commands, not as many players . . . It doesn't work the same way.

Sorry.